# How to start multiple validators in hyperledger sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

How to start multiple validators in hyperledger sawtooth and synchronize them?

Deploy same transaction processor on both of them  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple nodes on the same machine, with no VM, you need to have each node with its own set of TCP ports and own log/data file directories.

Use `$SAWTOOTH_HOME` to set a different base directory for each node.
Use the `sawtooth-validator --bind` options to set different ports for each node (network, component, consensus) and for the REST API in `sawtooth-rest-api --bind` and `--connect` options.

Here's an example for one node:
`sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-validator \
--bind component:tcp://127.0.0.1:4004 \
--bind network:tcp://127.0.0.1:8800 \
--endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8800 \
--peering static --peers tcp://127.0.0.1:8801`

And for the REST API:
`sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-rest-api --connect tcp://127.0.0.1:4004 \
          --bind 127.0.0.1:8008`
Then setup another node using port 8801, 4005 and 8009, for example, for the network, component, and REST API ports. Set `$SAWTOOTH_HOME` to be different for each one.

Here's a full working example, similar to the above (just extract the command line parts and run directly):
https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/sawtooth/topic/networking_validators_running/18059074?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,80,18059074

Comment: I am not able to do this because i am not able to finf SAWTOOTH_HOME in my machine

Comment: You need to set it up. You have a separate `$SAWTOOTH_HOME` for each Sawtooth node. It seems that this is too complicated for you to do--as I said it is not easy. I would use multiple virtual machines with something like VirtualBox, or multiple Docker containers. Here is a Docker Compose file that sets up a Sawtooth network using Docker: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-default-poet.yaml
Instructions are here if you need them: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/creating_sawtooth_network.html

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is starting all the same things you started on the first machine on each subsequent node with a few exceptions:

- Only one node should establish the genesis batch
- You may or may not need to set the `-peers` list on the validator command line or configuration file
- The validators will find each other and synchronize the blocks. This is why you must run the same transaction processors (TPs) on each node as well.

Comment: How to run a TP on both Validators?

Comment: I am not able to run two validators please provide me the command

Comment: Can You tell me how to do this practically

Comment: ubuntu native installation not docker

Comment: Here are the docs for 1.0.5 sawtooth-core: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0.5/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html